# Issue With Pear DB In Many Hosting Providers

Tags: php, hosting, pear

I Connect and Query My Db Using PEAR DB Like This:

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  , 'localhost')){
    $dsn = 'mysql://root:@localhost/xxx' ;
}else{
    $dsn = 'mysql://xxx:xxx@localhost/xxx' ;
}
$dbc =& DB::connect($dsn);
$dbc->query("set names utf8" );
if (PEAR::isError($dbc , array('debug'=>3))) {
    die($dbc->getMessage());
}
```

In some hosting providers it's working perfectly and for example, if the database user doesn't have sufficient permissions, it says: **Insufficient Permission**, and some other errors. Also, when I fix the problem, the site will come up and runs well.

However, in many hosting providers it doesn't show many errors! And nothing on the page either! The page is completely blank, no errors, no notice, nothing! I've also set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in top of my script, and I still can't find the bug. Is there any solution for such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure display_errors is on (or check the logs):

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Comment: @Greg i check Both and set display_errors true but still nothing ! No errors and nothing in log file

Comment: That's interesting... A white page is usually a symptom of running out of memory, or sometimes bad encoding.  I'd recommend checking your error logs

Comment: A white page is a symptom of any unreported error, not just encoding or memory issues.

Comment: @Mike B Yes, a segfault can also cause a white page, and probably others but in my experience it's usually memory - anything else will be displayed